# Debug mode shows Strict Standards

Tags: errors

When I set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in `wp-config.php`, I get to see all the strict standards and deprecated messages.

I've set the `error_reporting` in my `php.ini`, `ini_set()` and `error_reporting()` to `E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE`. But I still get to see the strict standards messages.

I know the messages can be useful, but they appear in some of the plugins I am using and I am not interested in seeing them. How do I disable them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don’t set `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE`. The error level is set in `wp_debug_mode()`, which is called in `wp-settings.php` before any plugins are loaded. If you leave the default values WordPress will set it to:

```
error_reporting( 
    E_CORE_ERROR | 
    E_CORE_WARNING | 
    E_COMPILE_ERROR | 
    E_ERROR | 
    E_WARNING | 
    E_PARSE | 
    E_USER_ERROR | 
    E_USER_WARNING | 
    E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR 
);
```

But you *should* keep strict standard messages on, because in some cases they advance to real errors in later PHP versions, so it is better to fix them early.

Answer (score 2):

To hide strict errors you could use the solution provided by RadGH [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579637/disabling-strict-standards-errors-in-wordpress-3-7-with-php-5-4#comment32307102_19618453): just put the following code in a must use plugin (a single php file under /wp-content/mu-plugins/)

```
if (WP_DEBUG && WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY) 
{
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
}
```